# How to display received data bytes via Bluetooth properly?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, spp

I have a problem with receiving data via BT, sent from SPP BT module. When I'm sending bytes from terminal i got non-sense characters - for example "[B@420e98d8". There is a part of the code from handler responsible for data receive:

```
        mHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg){
            if(msg.what == MESSAGE_READ){
                try {
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    byte[] bytes = (msg.obj).toString().getBytes();

                    mReadBuffer.setText(readBuf.toString());
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            if(msg.what == CONNECTING_STATUS){
                if(msg.arg1 == 1)
                    mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connected to Device: " + (String)(msg.obj));
                else
                    mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connection Failed");
            }
        }
    };
```

How should I convert received values to display them properly? Or how to receive this otherwise?
I don't need to use BLE, normal Bluetooth module, programming in Android Studio 2.2.3.

Comment: What is "properly"?  They're bytes, so `[B@420e98d8` is perfectly valid.

Comment: No its not valid and that is not the content of the bytes array but a java identifier.

Comment: Try something like mReadBuffer.setText((String)msg.obj);

Comment: Are you shure the bytes contain text?

Comment: Google for java convert byte array to string.

Comment: tried mReadBuffer.setText((String)msg.obj);, app crashed, tried using NullPointerException instead of UnsupportedEncodingException (due to "never thrown in the corresponding try block error"), app also crashed.
I can't even debug it, because android studio can't see my device.

Comment: You need to do something with the bytes in readBuf. Do you want to parse them as a string in utf8 or print the hex of each byte?

Comment: I want to print the hex of each byte.